# Website redirection based in ie browser version

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a website running which is supported by IE8. I want replace this with a new website,but the new website is not supported by IE8. Is there some way where i can redirect the new website to show the old website itself if the browser version is less than IE9.
(website is completely in html n css)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write these line at the top

```
 <!--[if IE 8 ]>   <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://oldurl.com"> <![endif]-->
```

replace oldurl.com with your ie8 supported url

Comment: It worked. i had to exit the browser and clear cache. Thanks a lot sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

First set up your ie classes correctly

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
And add some simple script:

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    // Detecting IE
    var oldIE;
    if ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8')) {
        oldIE = true;
    }

    if (oldIE) {
        window.location.href="new url";
    } else {
        // ..And here's the full-fat code for everyone else
    }

}(jQuery));
```

Source - http://www.paulirish.com/

Comment: This is browser sniffing technique. Not at all recommended.

Comment: Also, the documentation on the `index.html` from HTML5 Boilerplate is worth a read. https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/doc/html.md